# static resources are not loaded for an application deployed on weblogic12c

Tags: weblogic

I deployed a web application on WebLogic 12c (12.1.3) and when I hitting the login page, I get a `HTTP-200` response for the `login.html` but the js and css files which are included in the login.html, not getting loaded and throwing `HTTP-404` error.
Like below js is included in html

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/validation.js"/>
```

For `validation.js` getting http 404 error.

The resources folder is already under the application home directory.

I am new to weblogic. 
Let me know if any configurations are required to set to get these js-files loaded whenever required for an application.

Comment: What is the context path for your application as defined in the `web.xml` or  `application.xml`. You may just need to prefix this on the `src` path of your script import.

Comment: Thanks ! I am able to get the static contents after adding dot (.) in the src attribute like  src="./resources/js/validation.js"

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the static contents after adding dot (.) in the src attribute like below

script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/validation.js" />